# Create a new fetch request on button click - SWR / React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, swr

I am building a trivia app using the [OpenTBD](https://opentdb.com/) API.

I use SWR to make my API requests and get the questions and answers I want to display when my component renders

API call:

```
import useSWR from "swr";

export function useFetch(category, amount, difficulty) {
  const url = `https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=${amount}&category=${category}&difficulty=${difficulty}&type=multiple`;
  const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then((res) => res.json());

  const { data, error } = useSWR(url, fetcher, {
    revalidateOnFocus: false,
  });

  return {
    data: data,
    isLoading: !error && !data,
    isError: error,
  };
}
```

Component :

```
function Quiz() {
  const { category, color } = useSelector((state) => state.start);
  const { amount, difficulty } = useSelector((state) => state.settings);
  const gameEnded = useSelector((state) => state.end.isEnded);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { data, isLoading, isError } = useFetch(category, amount, difficulty);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <FlowerSpinner color={color} />;
  }

  if (isError) {
    return <div>An error has occured.</div>;
  }

  dispatch(updateQuestions(createQuestions(data.results)));

  return (
    <>
      <Questions />
      {gameEnded ? <PlayAgainBtn /> : <VerifyButton />}
    </>
  );
}

export default Quiz;
```

This works fine but now, when the game is over, I have a "Play Again" button that's displayed and I'd like to add an on click to create a new fetch in order to get a new set of questions.
I can't call the useFetch hook within a function like doing :

```
<button onClick={() => useFetch(newArgs)} />
```

so I tried to use `mutate` but I think because I am using the same url (the amount, category and difficulty doesn't change) when I call mutate, no new data is fetched

Answer (score 1):

You could try [conditional fetching](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/conditional-fetching) which has worked for me before. I can't remember if it invalidates the cache of SWR but I recall it being the correct answer over `mutate`. My thought is that when you select the "Play Again" button, you could have a state such as

```
const [playAgain, setPlayAgain] = useState(false)
```

This gets passed to `useFetch` and you can structure useSWR like so:

```
const { data, error } = useSWR(playAgain ? url : null, fetcher, {
    revalidateOnFocus: false,
  });
```

You'll need to come up with a solution for the first playthrough but that very well could be another state to handle that.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I tried to do it with conditional fetching but I kept running into errors so I ended up using Suspense and fetching with axios

Comment: Also a reasonable approach @EnzoFilippo, sometimes SWR doesn't behave as one might assume.